# IE how to open new window to view pdf stream instead save and open file

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, blob

Java Web application:
I did some researches to view pdf data retrieved from server, an "application/pdf" content response.
Below js works but in IE it open/saves a pdf file instead of opening a new window to display pdf.
How to open a new window for IE?

```
var res = $http.post(printURL, dataset, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});

res.success(function(response, status, headers, config) {

var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});

if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
   window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file);

}

else{
   var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
   window.open(fileURL);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `.htaccess` file.

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="yourfile.pdf"
```

Note that you'll need to change `filename`, which in the example is **yourfile.pdf**, to whatever the file you're trying to force open in the browser.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a good approach, I will test shortly and keep you updated.